# Are there flaws in my current understanding of classes and functions?

Tags: python, django, class, oop

I have just started learning about Django and have finished classes and objects in Python. One common snippet that I see all the time is:

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Is it ok to say that there is some file called django.db in the system and there is a class called models inside it and Model is an attribute of the class? Also, django.db is not a Python (.py) file, so how can it contain a class?

Now, Is CharField is function inside the class models or is it something else?

Comment: If a directory contains a file named `__init__.py` then when you import that directory you are actually "importing" `__init__.py`

Comment: Which part of the question are you referring to?

Comment: There is a directory in `django/models` named "db". When you run `from django.db import models` then `django/db/models/__init__.py` is being returned. `django/db/models/__init__.py` imports `Model` and is thus available as an attribute of the module

Comment: And when we run `django.db import models` why does it only import `__init__.py` and not all the .py files in the models directory?

Comment: Because that's the way the Python works. `django/db/models/__init__.py` actually imports the vast majority of classes from all of the `.py` files in the directory and they are thus available on the module - `models.CharField` and all the other fields are a good example of this

Comment: So "CharField" is a function defined in __some__ .py file that was imported by `django/db/models/__init__.py`, right?

Comment: Also, if possible please add your comments as an answer to the question so I can accept it. :) Thank you so much